# when captcha is wrong form data is lost

Tags: php

I have form for my word press website which user can enter some information. In my form I have captcha image which user has enter manually. The problem is when user enters wrong captcha the form data which he filled also losing. Is there is any way to refresh the captcha with out losing the form data? Help me out... Thanks in advance...

Comment: of course it's gone, because it's *another* form already. You have to fill form fields manually. Don't forget to `htmlspecialchars()` the values. Or use AJAX to submit form, as mentioned below. But you have to check all fields, not captcha only. There can be other errors and fields should be filled as well

Answer (score 1):

You should check in your serverside code if the captcha was successful, and if not, repopulate the form with the data the user sent.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go for popular [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). Users are able to refresh the captcha code there and then through ajax and after that they can submit the form which makes sure that code you enter is what it is.